# SQL count Order start from GOB

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, date

I'm

I've got a little problem i match some files every day fot UPDATE my DATABASE.
I would like to count how many order start by "GOB" i've since 1 month day by day on my Table "ORDER"

```
id|last_update
gogo2132|27/08/2013 00:00:00
gob00000|27/08/2013 00:00:00
gob00001|27/08/2013 00:00:00
gob00002|27/08/2013 00:00:00
gob00003|28/08/2013 00:00:00
```

The result i need

```
Day|count"only id start by gob)
27/08/2013| 3
28/08/2013| 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking following Code.

```
Select count(*),order_date From Table
Where Left(id,3) = 'Gob' And DateDiff(d,order_date,getdate()) <= 30
Group by order_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orderdate, COUNT(*)
FROM `ORDER`
WHERE orderid LIKE 'GOB%'
GROUP BY orderdate
ORDER BY orderdate DESC
```

This would be a dayly count, if orderdate does not contain time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orderdate, COUNT(*)
FROM `ORDER`
WHERE orderid LIKE 'gob%' AND last_update= (SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY DAY(last_update)
```